# Split string by regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have `[110308] Asia and India` string and I want only `Asia and India` as my result by regular expression.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Sorry, but regex is new to me. So I don't know how to do it.

Comment: So you want to split after the first `]` character in your string or...?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Yes, I want string after `] `.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP should have a minimal understanding of the problem, post what they have tried and what went wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do without regex you can try

```
>>> '[110308] Asia and India'.split(']', 1)[-1].strip()
'Asia and India'
```

or just use `lstrip`

```
>>> '[110308] Asia and India'.lstrip(" []" + string.digits)
'Asia and India'
```

Or, if for reasons you want to stick with regex

```
>>> re.findall("^[\[\]\d ]*(.*)"," [110308] Asia and India")[0]
'Asia and India'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
re.findall('[^0-9\[\]]+', '[110308] Asia and India')[0].strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

With regex try replacing `[^a-zA-Z ]` with an empty string.

Comment: What if the string is `[123456] St. Thomas Island`?

Comment: I was only working with the example but if there are '-' or '.' that need to be taken into account then it would read [^a-zA-Z \.\-]

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
re.split('[0-9\[\]]+ +', '[110308] Asia and India')[1]
```